# SQL joins from 2 tables, grouped by joined data from a third

Tags: mysql, join

Title confusing?  :)

I'm trying to generate a useful report from my shopping cart database.

There's a table `orders` that contains "date_ordered" (and a bunch of other stuff I don't care about) and a key "orders_id"

A second table, `orders_products`, has the same "orders_id" key and has info about what was ordered.  In particular, I'm interested in "products_id", "products_quantity", and "final_price"

What I want to do is generate a sales report showing the sum of quantity*price and grouped by products_id when the date_ordered is between two dates.  And I can do that with this:

```
SELECT op.products_id AS 'PID',
    SUM(op.products_quantity) AS 'sales Q',
    SUM(op.final_price * op.products_quantity) AS 'sales $'
FROM orders o
JOIN orders_products op
ON o.orders_id = op.orders_id
WHERE o.date_purchased
BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-12-31'
GROUP BY op.products_id
```

That appears to work OK.   But now I "simply" wanted to add another column to the report which showed the products name.  That data is in yet another table, `products_description` in a column "products_name".  So I tried this:

```
SELECT pd.products_name AS 'Product',
    op.products_id AS 'PID',
    SUM(op.products_quantity) AS 'sales Q',
    SUM(op.final_price * op.products_quantity) AS 'sales $'
FROM orders o
JOIN orders_products op
ON o.orders_id = op.orders_id
JOIN products_description pd
ON op.products_id = pd.products_id
WHERE o.date_purchased
BETWEEN '2012-01-01' and '2012-12-31'
GROUP BY op.products_id
```

And at first it appeared to work, until I noticed all the sales Q and sales $ figures were 3x what they should be.

Its moved beyond my ability to grasp :)  Help appreciated.

Comment: try adding pd.products_name in the group by clause

Comment: If your figures for a product ID are multiplied by 3, I guess it's because the products_description tables contains 3 rows for the same product ID, doesn't it?

Comment: @Nikita... odd, that crashes the server! lol.  I tried rebooting and doing it again, same thing... it freezes.  WEIRD

Comment: You have to group by anything that you aren't aggregating. So if you want the product name and also the other sums, you have to add ProductName to the group by.

Comment: Darn it... I just realized Walid and Drapp are right.  I *do* have triple entries in products_descriptions.  I wasn't considering two unused entries for different languages that got installed by default.  Sigh.  Sorry for wasting your guys' time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another thing... as others noted about adding the product name to the group by clause, you appear to still have some sort of Cartesian result. Without knowing the actual data, you might want to wrap your query up something like...

```
select
      pd.products_name AS 'Product',
      PreQuery.*
   from
      ( SELECT 
              op.products_id AS 'PID',
              SUM(op.products_quantity) AS 'sales Q',
              SUM(op.final_price * op.products_quantity) AS 'sales $'
           FROM 
              orders o
                 JOIN orders_products op
                    ON o.orders_id = op.orders_id
           WHERE 
              o.date_purchased BETWEEN '2012-01-01' and '2012-12-31'
           GROUP BY 
              op.products_id ) PreQuery
      JOIN products_description pd
         ON PreQuery.PID = pd.products_id
```

This should work as the internal query does the results all rolled-up on just the PID.  THEN, take that result and join to the product description table.

if you STILL get duplicates for each item, then your product description table would appear to have multiple records for the same product ID... such as there is a higher unique key, but there might be same product with multiple status, types, whatever causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks for showing me PreQuery... totally new concept to me.  As I noted above in a comment, you guys are right and there were triple entries in products_description.  So I'm annoyed at myself for not seeing it and for wasting your time... but I'm glad because I got to see a new way to do things!  Thanks.